# I use spring 4+ hibernate 4 encounter following error:

Tags: spring, hibernate

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: public
>   edu.java.spring.dao.impl.StudentHibernateDaoImpl
>   edu.java.spring.controller.StudentController.studentDAO; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: public
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
>   edu.java.spring.dao.impl.StudentHibernateDaoImpl.sessionFactory;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Can you post your spring xml or Configuration class?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about your config or your class there are 2 possible solutions:

1. Your not scanning the package containing the class
2. What u `@Autowired` is not annotated with anything Spring knows like `@Repositoy`, `@Service`,`@Component` etc